# Inserting pvc pipe into wall for kitchen drain

Tags: plumbing

I ripped out the pvc pipe from my kitchen drain and now would like to add a new one.

The kitchen drain is some sort of metal (cast iron I assume).

Do I just prime and put cement on the pvc pipe and the cast iron drain or is there some additional steps I need to follow to create a water tight seal and follow code to attach a piece of pvc pipe to a metal drain pipe?

[image]

Comment: Lepages PL faststik is the best adhesive and sealant /w caulking gun, although after 3 days, its not coming out with a lot of effort. Anything else might be gas tight until jarred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't just throw cement on a PVC pipe and shove it in there. You need to clean off the rust, corrosion and other debris that's in the cast iron pipe. Grind out the rough/rust spots so you have a smooth surface. Then get an compression donut from your plumbing store that fits in your cast iron pipe and also your PVC pipe. Follow the directions and you should be good to go..

(picture from Home Depot site)

[image]